# Get value of an attribute, where you don't know the name

Tags: xslt, xpath

Say if I have some XML with a line such as:

```
<machine center="10" left="25" right="162" />
```

and, using XSLT, I want to turn that in to something like:

```
<measurement type="center">10</measurement>
<measurement type="left">25</measurement>
<measurement type="right">162</measurement>
```

How do I do that?  At the moment I have the following, but am missing one crucial part:

```
<measurement>
  <xsl:for-each select="@">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
      <xsl:value-of name="name()">
    </xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:value-of name="[WHAT_GOES_HERE?]" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</measurement>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:value-of name="." />`?

Comment: Error: "name" attribute is not allowed on the xsl:value-of element! Error: xsl:value-of requires attribute: select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This solution is both: simpler/shorter, avoids `<xsl:for-exch>` and is fully in the spirit of XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="machine">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="machine/@*">
   <measurement type="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></measurement>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<machine center="10" left="25" right="162" />
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<measurement type="center">10</measurement>
<measurement type="left">25</measurement>
<measurement type="right">162</measurement>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way;

```
<xsl:template match="machine">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <measurement type="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </measurement>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Accepted @zx485's answer over this one due to:
(a) Lower rep for zx...
(b) his use of local-name(), which I'd not considered at all

But yours with that local-name would probably be the ultimate answer to this IMO :)

Comment: @AlgyTaylor Since your XML does not use prefixes, there will be no difference between local-name() and name(). YAGNI.

Comment: Good point, although my thinking was that for the 6 extra characters it's probably worth it on the (unlikely) offchance that the XML file will become namespaced at some point in the future. Totally agree there's no point in adding functionality for the sake of it, but in this case it's no extra work really ... unless there's a good reason that I'm overlooking?

Comment: If your XML will become namespaced, there will be a lot more work to be done. XSLT is custom work, not off-the-rack.

Comment: Excellent point ... probably best that it breaks quickly!! :)

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve this is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="machine">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="measurement">
                <xsl:attribute name="type">
                    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```